# Increment sparse matrix

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am currently manipulating a very huge matrix so I had to use CSR format like this : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

I managed to convert a normal matrix to a CSR matrix with the 3 arrays IA, JA and A like in the Wikipedia page.
However, I am still confused about this format. How can I do if for example I want to increment the element of line n and column m of the CSR matrix? If for example I want to increment the element at the line n and column m by 1, how will the 3 arrays change?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just quickly read through it but IA and JA both are indexing tables, the array actually containing the values is A. If all the non-zero values are positive then incrementing a non-zero value is trivial and will only modify A. However, what you're asking becomes tricky if some elements are negative or if you increment a cell containing a zero. Indeed, you will need to mutate A not just in a single index, but inserting an element potentially in the middle of the array and updating IA consequently. I think this format is simply terrible for the operation you're looking for, it will have linear worst-case complexity in those situations just for updating a single cell.